# Custom Method Route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, view

I've seen this question asked all over the place, but for seemingly no reason at all, I can't figure out how to Route a custom method in rails.

Quick Overview: I built a small application and generated a scaffold called answers. When I generated the scaffold, it automatically got its answers_controller.rb in the controller folder and its answers folder in the views.

In the answers_controller, i added one custom method called random. The entirety of answers_controller is below:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  @answers = Answer.all
end

def show
end

def random
end

def new
  @answer = Answer.new
end

def edit
end


def create
  @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @answer.save
    format.html { redirect_to @answer, notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @answer }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /answers/1
# DELETE /answers/1.json
def destroy
@answer.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to answers_url, notice: 'Answer was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
```

end

in my views/answers folder I made a folder called random.html.erb, which only contains an html h1 tag.
In my routes file, I have the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :answers

# this should work, why doesn't it???
resources :answers do
  collection do
    get :random
  end
end

root to: 'dashboard#index'
end
```

Every resource on the internet says this is the way to do it, but when i run localhost:3000/random I just get a routing error. I'm including a picture of the file structure, but for the life of me, I have no idea why this doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it:

```
get '/random/', to: 'answers#random', as: 'random'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your routes mean that this `random` action will be accessible via `/answers/random` path. Plus your `resources :answers` line (the one without block) should be removed.
You may find more info in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).